# goaccess log parsing of very simple log not working

Tags: parsing, logging, fatal-error, log-analysis, goaccess

*My first question in this community, hope it's gonna be awesome around here!*

To the topic: 
I have this very simple log file constructed in the following manner

```
192.168.178.21 [21/07/2015] "GET /path/to/somewhere HTTP/1.1" "/path/to/somewhere" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

and the following config file for goaccess

```
date-format %d/%m%Y
log-format %h %^[%d%^] "%r" "%U" %^
```

Side question:

- I could find several different ways to write the config file. In [the docs](http://goaccess.io/man#custom-log) one can find variable declarations of *date_format* and *log_format* which confuses me. Which is the correct one?

Since I looked through all related questions to this topic, i  couldn't find a reason why I get the error

```
GoAccess - version 0.8.5 - Dec  5 2014 06:28:46
Fatal error has occurred
Error occurred at: goaccess.c - main - 832
Nothing valid to process.
```

The documentation also states, that only %h, "%r" and %d are required for correct parsing. What am I missing?

**add. info**

- CentOS 7 64bit
- GoAccess 0.8.5

I know the newest version as of this day is 0.9.2. Out of "*reasons*", I cannot build the newest version by my own. So maybe it is a version depending problem (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your date format posted is not right. Try the following, it works for me:

```
goaccess -f log --log-format='%h [%d] "%r" "%^" "%u"' --date-format='%d/%m/%Y' --time-format="%T"
```

You have to use both, `date_format` and `log_format`, and I think `time_format` as well (at least in the latest version).

The variable `date_format` specifies the date format, while `log_format` contains the tokens that goaccess uses to parse each line from your access log.

Comment: That did the trick. thank you! Mistakes were (as you pointed out): unnecessary "%^" in front of the date declaration in the brackets "[ ]" and apparently the "%U" placeholder, which is described as "The URL path requested (including any query string)." in the docs, is responsible for this error aswell. Any idea why the "%U" isn't working?

Comment: the [doc](http://goaccess.io/man#custom-log) says that `%r` needs some sort of delimiter, otherwise, `%m` `%U` `%H` need to be used. Since your request contains three of them, `%r` works just fine. I guess you could do this too: `--log-format='%h [%d] "%m %^ %H" "%U" "%u"'`.

Comment: You are right of course. Should have read that more carefully. Consider this question to be closed. Ty.